# ValueError at /url/ The view frontend.views.url didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, forms, httprequest, ibm-cloud

I am writing a piece of code that will parse a page when user enters the url in the form field in a page: "url.html". When users enters the url in the form field, it comes here in this view(in the instance.web_url). However im getting this error of HTTPResponse object. Here's the code:

```
def url(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':   
       form_url =  WebURLForm(request.POST or None)
       title = "Search via URL here"
       instance = form_url.save(commit = False)
       instance.save()

       if instance.web_url == "":
          instance.web_url = "http://www.facebook.com/"
       print instance.web_url


       html = urllib.urlopen(instance.web_url).read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
       lines = []
# kill all script and style elements
       for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
           script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
       text = soup.get_text()

#break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
       lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
#break multi-headlines into a line each
       chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
#drop blank lines
       text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

       text=text.encode('utf-8')


       words = text.split(".")

       count=0
       terrorism_level=0
       for i in words:
           print count
           if not words[count]:
               words[count] = "this was empty before." 
           json_result = natural_language_classifier.classify('90e7b7x198-nlc-50734',words[count])
           classes =  json_result['classes']
           result = json.dumps(classes, indent=2)
           if (classes[0]['confidence'] > 0.98 and classes[0]['class_name'] == "nhate."):
               print words[count]
               print result
           terrorism_level +=1
           count=count+1     

       context = {"form_url":form_url, "title":title}
       return render(request,'url.html',context)
```

Comment: What happens if the request method is not POST?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem is, i have a page url.html in which i have a form field. Now when ever i open the page, it starts processing the view and gives the result on command prompt and the page keeps on loading. My assumption is that it sees the GET request so it starts to process the view. So thats why, I have this condition that if the request is POST, then process all this view.

Answer (score 1):

```
def url(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':   
       form_url =  WebURLForm(request.POST or None)
       title = "Search via URL here"
       instance = form_url.save(commit = False)
       instance.save()

       if instance.web_url == "":
          instance.web_url = "http://www.facebook.com/"
       print instance.web_url


       html = urllib.urlopen(instance.web_url).read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
       lines = []
# kill all script and style elements
       for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
           script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
       text = soup.get_text()

#break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
       lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
#break multi-headlines into a line each
       chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
#drop blank lines
       text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

       text=text.encode('utf-8')


       words = text.split(".")

       count=0
       terrorism_level=0
       for i in words:
           print count
           if not words[count]:
               words[count] = "this was empty before." 
           json_result = natural_language_classifier.classify('90e7b7x198-nlc-50734',words[count])
           classes =  json_result['classes']
           result = json.dumps(classes, indent=2)
           if (classes[0]['confidence'] > 0.98 and classes[0]['class_name'] == "nhate."):
               print words[count]
               print result
           terrorism_level +=1
           count=count+1     

       context = {"form_url":form_url, "title":title}
       else:
           form_url = WebURLForm()
           context = {"form_url":form_url, "title":None}
    return render(request,'url.html',context)
```

try this once

Comment: Its still giving the same error, it isnt about the indentation.

Comment: its easy bro. you only checked for POST method, but when the webpage first loads it gets a GET method, thats what i added in else part, so when a user visits the page first time the form is loaded and the webpage gets a GET request. hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Because you probably called the view using `GET` method. Also, please read Python tutorial and PEP-8. Your code has ugly formatting and doesn't conform to PEP-8 standard.